# Should I continue stressing development standards?

Tags: coding-standards, team, conventions

I've been with my software team for about three years now, and just recently I brought up the concept of variable naming conventions (across all languages, but C#/VB.Net specifically).

We really don't have any solid naming conventions.  I was met with serious resistance - so what?, does it really matter?, blank stares, etc.

I was able to get the others to agree to at least be consistent on a given code file (not ideal, but with this group, any standards that is based around anything other than SQL is a step forward).

My question is this - I've always received resistance to developing standards.

- Should I just stop pushing standards and accept the fact that everyone seems to be doing their own thing when they code?

Comment: Microsoft has already [done the leg work for you.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) Why not simply adopt their standards?  Every development team should have a coding standard.  Everyone on the team should follow it, and it should be enforced by a code formatter or some sort of linting program.  There are many reasons why this is a good thing; consistency is the most important one.  Not being regarded as amateurs is another.

Comment: Most programmers are immersed in solving real problems. They just don't want to hear about how they're notPushingTheShiftKeyEnoughForMicrosoftsLiking. Over time, I've come to believe that the best variable names look-like-this (which is a very easy standard to type and to read); in languages where that's not allowed, I think programmers should mostly be left to their own devices in dealing with this deficiency. I'm not advocating complete chaos, but most people who actually get paid to code are, in my experience, responsible enough to avoid really bad names on their own.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Microsoft also preached Hungarian notation once upon a time.

Comment: @user1172763: Following the shop's coding standards requires the least amount of time and effort, and assures consistency within the project.  It doesn't have to be the Microsoft standard, but it does need to be the same standard for everyone on the project.  It's not about your personal preferences.

Comment: @ckuhn203: You're vastly oversimplifying the Hungarian issue.  There are two types of Hungarian; one that has significant value, and one that doesn't.  The one that has significant value allows you to discern the type and usage of a variable from a few letters in the variable name. Intellisense has largely subsumed this function in modern IDEs, and the newer naming conventions (which lack Hungarian prefixes) are quite sensible, since Hungarian is no longer required.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes. I will give it to you that I am hugely over simplifying the Hungarian issue. I'm merely pointing out that blindly following Microsoft's recommendations may not be for the best. Although, I would agree that it's a great starting point and better than nothing.

Comment: @user1172763 I completely disagree with you. It shows that you do not pay enough attention to detail if you use inconsistent or incorrect naming conventions. How could anyone trust your code if you can't even get something basic like using the correct naming conventions?

Comment: @ckuhn203 They didn't just preach it, they were the first major company to actually use the bastardised version we know today, as the original paper outlined I'd love it(you designate variables based on things like error/sanity checking, database sterilisation, display sanitised etc.).

Comment: @Stephen, I feel that trustworthy code originates from an understanding of concepts: of the request-response model, of the stack and heap, of threads, or whatever the building blocks in use may be. Code that looks neat because its author aped some smarter coder's style, well, *looks* neat. And having too many extra-syntactical "remember to..." rules is a human factors anti-pattern, as is making me use Shift excessively. That said, when I deliver a product, it is internally consistent with respect to naming, e.g. http://beaugg.blogspot.com/2014/07/3d-space-flight-demo-for-android-os.html#naming

Answer (score 7):

**Don't quit yet. Try the following first.**

Sell them the idea differently. Sell them the idea as *"code quality"*.

**If you are the boss:**

- Tell them that they need to improve the **quality of their code**.
- Tell them that the naming convention is the major aspect to be considered in the first phase.
- Tell them that code quality is going to be considered in their performance appraisal.

**If you are only their peer:**

- Tell them they don't have to change the code that is already done, but apply the conventions in the new code they write.
- Use the convention yourself.
- Clarify that you are not inventing some in-house convention but using the universally-accepted convention of any given language, the one the official documentation of the language uses.
- Prepare a presentation about the benefits of adopting a naming convention.
- Talk about the collective ownership of code. They shouldn't apply personal criteria to code that is everyone's to maintain.
- Plot/print a poster-sized naming convention cheat-sheet and display it in your cubicle. Offer to plot/print a copy for whomever shows interest.

**Do you use unit tests ?**

- Refactor mercilessly whenever you feel like it. Unit tests will have your back.

**If nothing works:**

- Be faithful to yourself and continue to provide an example.
- Remember work is only a part of life. Pursue other, more worthy aims.